# How to show that the infinite sum of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ is $e^x$ without knowledge of the derivative of $e^x$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I am aware that this is the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ but how would people have known that the taylor expansion whose derivative is itself is the exponential function $e^x$.

Comment: It’s the infinite sum of $\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$ not $\frac{1}{n!}$

Comment: infinite sum of 1/n! is e not eˣ.

Comment: The question is unclear. How do you define $e^x$?

Comment: Probably use the definition of limit for $e$. Then you would get the answer by simple binomial theorem(expansion).

Comment: There are several characterizations of the exponential function.  Given one such characterization of $\exp(x)$, one can show that $\exp(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$.  See [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function#Characterizations).

Comment: You can write down a generic power series, differentiate it term by term, set the derivative equal to the original function, and solve for the coefficients in the power series.

Answer (score 0):

*Hope this will help a lot.
Here are answers different from using Taylor expansion.*

[Why does the sum of the reciprocals of factorials converge to $e$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1054175/469000)

Comment: Rather than posting a link to a different MSE question, please just flag as a duplicate. In general, link-only answers should be avoided and are more appropriate as comments.

Comment: ok i'll. I am new here thats why i dont know much but next time i'll do.

Comment: No problem (and I didn't vote on your answer FWIW).

Answer (score 0):

HINT: let $f(x):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$, then start showing, using binomial expansion and absolute convergence, that $f(x+y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$.

Then show that $f(1)=e$, hence $f(n)=e^n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. Do the same for the cases $f(1/n)$ noticing that $f(n)\cdot f(1/n)=f(1)$ and that $f(-n)=\frac1{f(n)}$.

Then you knows now that $f(q)=e^q$ for all $q\in\Bbb Q$. Now use the locally uniform convergence of the series to show that $f$ is continuous, hence $$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(q_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{q_n}$$ for any sequence of rationals $(q_n)$ that converge to $x$. By last you will need [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/722932/173262) to show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{q_n}=e^x$$